# The Trouble With Tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I know this is a beginner question but we all gotta begin somewhere (and yes, I did look around on SO and YT).

I write this:

```
firstName = ['Charles', 'Steve', 'Mary']
lastName = ['Manley', 'Perry', 'Shelly']
fullName = zip(firstName, lastName)

sayHelloTo = fullName
for i in sayHelloTo:
     print('Hello ' + i)
```

hoping to get this:

```
Hello Charles Manley
Hello Steve Perry
Hello Mary Shelly
```

How am I misunderstanding making the list into a tuple? What's the correct way of writing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Something which none of the answers have addressed is variable names. [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends following the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This gives exactly what you want:**

```
firstName = ['Charles', 'Steve', 'Mary']
lastName = ['Manley', 'Perry', 'Shelly']
fullName = zip(firstName, lastName)

#unpack
for i,j in fullName:
    print("Hello {} {}".format(i,j))
```

Prints:

```
Hello Charles Manley
Hello Steve Perry
Hello Mary Shelly
```

Comment: Ah-hem: `print(f'Hello {i} {j}')` ;)

Comment: f-strings were introduced in python 3. I am covering also python 2 in my answer. Cheers

Answer (score 4):

When you iterate with `for i in sayHelloTo` you are assigning the whole tuple to the variable `i` in each iteration of the loop, so your print statement is printing "Hello " plus the whole tuple.

Because each tuple contains two elements (first and last name), to properly format each element of the tuple in the print statement you need to fully unpack the tuple, as in:

```
for first, last in sayHelloTo:
    print('Hello ' + first +" "+ last)
```

Or using f-strings to simplify the print statement:

```
for first, last in sayHelloTo:
    print(f'Hello {first} {last}')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use iterable argument unpacking with the `*` operator:

```
for i in sayHelloTo:
    print('Hello', *i)
```

This outputs:

```
Hello Charles Manley
Hello Steve Perry
Hello Mary Shelly
```

Answer (score 1):

No Need to create tuple before for loop. you can do it at run time. Since you want to use tuple,it contains two values, so you need two variables to unpack them in for loop.

try following:

```
firstName = ['Charles', 'Steve', 'Mary']
lastName = ['Manley', 'Perry', 'Shelly']


for i,j in zip(firstName,lastName):
     print('Hello ' + i + ' ' +j)
```

if you are using python 3.6+ you can do something like as follow:

```
for i, j in zip(firstName, lastName):
    print (f'Hello {i} {j}')
```

EDIT: 
As suggested by user, updated f-string requirement to python 3.6 .

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is no difference here between assigning the result of the `zip()` to a variable or running it directly at the top of the loop.

Comment: The code block you have will crash, `sayHelloTo = fullName` -- `fullName` is not defined. Additionally, `f-strings` only work for python 3.6+, not 3.0+.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Yes, there is no difference between assigning result to variable and directly using it. Although, It's my personal preference to not to use variable just for the sake of iteration.

Comment: @Prish Makes sense, I was just confused by the sentence _No Need to create tuple before for loop. you can do it at run time._

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace your print line with this:

```py
print('Hello ' + ' '.join(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `sayHelloTo` to have the full names in a list. You can try the following code.

```
sayHelloTo = map(lambda pair: pair[0] + " " + pair[1], zip(firstName, lastName))
```

I think the point of misunderstanding is that zip creates a pair of items.